# React Native with Jest - cannot read property <propName> of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs

I'm using Jest and React Test Renderer to test a React Native component in which I add some params to the react-navigation object on mount, like so:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const { setParams } = this.props.navigation;

    setParams({ subTitle: this.props.user.outlet.name.toUpperCase() });
  }
```

This works fine in the UI, but in tests i get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'outlet' of undefined`

Passing `navigation` through as a prop works fine, but I presume I'm not passing `user` through correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my test (anything I didn't think relevant omitted):

```
const props = {
  navigation: {
    navigate: jest.fn()
  },
  user: {
    // user info here
  }
};

const tree = renderer.create(
    <MockApp mocks={{ ...baseMocks, ...mocks }}>
      <Home {...props} />
    </MockApp>
  );

await wait(0);

expect(tree.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();
```

Comment: Hmm...I get `TypeError: setParams is not a function` since the `navigation` mock doesn't include `setParams`

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Perhaps not a perfect solution, but given I couldn't understand why this was failing in the first place I've made the tests pass by checking for the presence of `user` in my component:

```
user &&
  user.outlet &&
  navigation.setParams({ subTitle: user.outlet.name.toUpperCase() });
```

Would love for someone to explain why this wasn't working in the first place though...